# SFML c++ create multiply objects and call at the constructor?

Tags: c++, sfml

Hello fellas when I'm trying to create multiply objects from a object and want to call for the constructor I'm getting som strange error.

the error is: **a value of type const cha*r cannot be used to initialize an entity of type Obstacle[3]**
Creating objects here referes to the Player object because it works, even if I try to for-loop to set my ("img....") I'm getting the same error

```
static const int CAP = 3;
//Works! Player player = ("img/playerSheet.png");
Obstacle obstacles[CAP] =("img/obstacle.png");
```

The Obstacle constructor looks like this

```
Obstacle::Obstacle(string spriteSearch) : Object(spriteSearch)
 {
setPosition(750, 500);
 }
```

//Filip

Comment: Replace those parentheses with curly braces: `{}`. Note that this will call the default constructor for every other object for which arguments weren't given, so make sure you have one.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the incorrect method of declaring an array. You create an array that holds three objects. You need to initialize each object with the default constructor. Here is one way to do it.
If you havent seen structs before, dont worry. All you need to know it works like a small class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Object
{
    string name;
    Object(string _name)
    {
        name = _name;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Object obs[3] = {"one", "two", "three"};

    cout<<obs[0].name<<obs[1].name<<obs[2].name<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Edit; If you have a large capacity, say 1000. I would suggest adding a seperate function. Where you dont initialize in the default constructor, but actually creates an Initialize function. That you call after. As an example;

```
Obstacle obstacles[CAP]; 
for(int i=0; i<CAP; i++) 
{ 
     obstacles[i].Initialize("img/playerSheet.png"); 
}
```

Comment: "Alright, i just edited the constructor above i wrote wrong before... so you mean to forloop and the how do i call the constructor, like obstaclei;? :O"

I might be in the wrong here. But I think in order to call the actual constructor, the only way is to do it like this:

Change:

```
Obstacle obstacles[CAP] =("img/obstacle.png");
```

to something like;

```
const int CAP = 5;
Object** obstacles = new Object*[CAP];

for(int i = 0; i<CAP; i++)
{
    obstacles[i] = new Object(filename);
}

//Do other stuff. And when done, release memory.

for(int i=0; i<CAP; i++)
{
    delete obstacles[i];
}
delete []obstacles;
```

It's fairly complicated solution if you are not used to using pointers.

Comment: Thanks would something like this work Obstacle obstacles[CAP] = { "img/playerSheet.png", "img/playerSheet.png", "img/playerSheet.png" };

Comment: Yes. If it is a large variable, like if you had 1000 as a capacity. I would suggest just doing a pointer out of it.

Comment: ´code´Obstacle::Obstacle(string spriteSearch) : Object(spriteSearch)
{
 setPosition(750, 500);
}´code´ I beleve it will call the default constructor but I want to call this constructor

Comment: Alright, i just edited the constructor above i wrote wrong before... so you mean to forloop and the how do i call the constructor, like obstacle[i]("img");? :O